# Cannot use File.Delete()_ to delete file locked to process on Win 7

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a C# Winforms application in which I delete a video file being viewed by an axWindowsMediaPlayer control, which keeps the file DestFile open while the video is playing. In Win 10, I can delete DestFile and then replace it with a copy of the file with modified metadata using a

```
File.Delete(DestFile)
```

command followed by

```
File.Move(SourceFile, DestFile) .
```

In Win 7 (64 bit) the

```
File.Delete
```

fails silently, and the

```
File.Move
```

fails with the message

```
Cannot create a file which alreday exists.
```

Is there a way of making Win  behave like Win 10 and allow deletion of file which is open to a process (as shown by OpenedFiles utility)?

Comment: SO you are saying, you are able to delete a file that is being used by another process and move in another file, and it all works fine? i think there is more to this story. You cant delete a file that has an open handle to it (AFAIK)

Comment: Seems as though you can do this in Win 10 but not in Win 7...

Answer (score 0):

Found that closing axWindowsMediaPlayer, performing Delete and Move and reopening axWindowsMediaPlayer as shown below worked on Win 7

```
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.clear();
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = null;

 System.IO.File.Delete(sFileAction);
 System.IO.File.Move(sDestFile, sFileAction);

 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newPlaylist("aa", "");
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.clear();
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(sFileAction));
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();`
```